# How can I duplicate the example in longtable.pdf?

Tags: longtable, examples

How can I duplicate the example in longtable.pdf?  I see several features in the example table from the longtable package documentation pages 2 & 3.  I want to build an example from that table.  I can see it in the dtx, but cannot get my sample to work.

Comment: The answer to your question is in the dtx as you note. You should ask your real question. As it stands, we have no idea what your problem is.

Comment: My real question is how can i read and play with the example.  The dtx format is not clear.  I do not care about the formatting of the rest of the article, just the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just copied and pasted the table, removed the comments, and then added the definition of `\env` and `\v` and made `"` a short verb command, more or less the same way that `longtable.dtx` does.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{shortvrb}
\newcommand*\env[1]{\textsl{#1}}
\MakeShortVerb{\"}
\def\v{\char`}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{*}r||p{1in}@{*}}
KILLED & LINE!!!! \kill
\caption
[An optional table caption (used in the list of tables)]
{A long table\label{long}}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{*}c@{*}}%
     {This part appears at the top of the table}\\
\textsc{First}&\textsc{Second}\\
\hline\hline
\endfirsthead
\caption[]{(continued)}\\
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{2}{@{*}c@{*}}%
      {This part appears at the top of every other page}\\
\textbf{First}&\textbf{Second}\\
\hline\hline
\endhead
\hline
This goes at the&bottom.\\
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
These lines will&appear\\
in place of the & usual foot\\
at the end& of the table\\
\hline
\endlastfoot
\env{longtable}  columns  are specified& in the \\
same way as  in the \env{tabular}& environment.\\
"@{*}r||p{1in}@{*}"& in this case.\\
Each row ends with a& "\\" command.\\
The "\\"  command  has an& optional\\
argument, just as in& the\\
 \env{tabular}&environment.\\[10pt]
See the  effect  of "\\[10pt]"&?\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Also  "\hline"  may be used,&  as in \env{tabular}.\\
\hline
That  was a "\hline"&.\\
\hline\hline
That  was "\hline\hline"&.\\
\multicolumn{2}{||c||}%
{This is a \ttfamily\v\\multicolumn\v{2\v}\v{||c||\v}}\\
If a  page break  occurs at a "\hline" then& a line is drawn\\
at the bottom of one  page  and at the& top of the next.\\
\hline
The  "[t] [b] [c]"  argument of \env{tabular}& can  not be used.\\
The optional argument may be  one of& "[l] [r] [c]"\\
to specify whether  the  table  should be& adjusted\\
to the  left, right& or centrally.\\
\hline\hline
L    ots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Some lines may take up a lot of space, like this: &
    \raggedleft This last column is a ``p'' column so this
    ``row'' of the table can take up several lines. Note however that
    \TeX\ will  never break a page within such a row. Page breaks only
    occur between rows of the table or at "\hline" commands.
    \tabularnewline
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.\\
\hline
Lots\footnote{This is a footnote.} of lines& like this.\\
Lots   of   lines& like this\footnote{\env{longtable} takes special
    precautions, so that footnotes may also be used in `p' columns.}\\
\hline
Lots of lines& like this.\\
Lots of lines& like this.
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Your earlier comment and down votes assume that I know enough about Latex commands to know what is important in the dtx file.  I did not.  I do a little more now.

Comment: @sbj3: I didn't down vote your question. I didn't vote on it at all.